# Angular: What is a directive property? But a method?

Tags: angular

I'm studying the Angular documentation and I saw that some directives have some properties and methods.

For example the [routerLinkActive](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive) has a property named `isActive: boolean` and a method `ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void`.

Can I use the `isActive` property and the `ngOnChanges` method? If the answer is positive, can you give me an example of how to use `isActive` and `ngOnChanges`?

Comment: No-one would do that. This seems like a [XY issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Instead of asking us what you think is the solution, please provide a [mcve] of your issue and explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @trichetriche I'm new to angular and I'm trying to do some basic stuff, so I don't want to ask trivial questions (there are a lot of these) and make things to work. I'm trying to understand the documentation in order to have a better understanding of what I can do.

Comment: Okay, I'll make an answer to the question "I'm trying to understand the documentation" then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following my comments, I'm going to explain the documentation to you.

The documentation for [`routerLinkActive`](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive) starts with a little chip on the top of the page :

[image: routerLinkActive component type]

This chip means that `routerLinkActive` is a directive. After extensive reading of the documentation, you will see that there is two types of directives : [attribute](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives) and [structural](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives). After reading both, you will understand that `routerLinkActive` is an **attribute** directive.

This means that you must use this directive on HTML elements, through its selector.

[image: RouterLinkActive selector]

This is a CSS selector that tells you how to use the directive.

By writing

```
<div routerLinkActive="XXX"></div>
```

You will create an instance of the directive on that element (which is explained in the documentation I have provided earlier).

Built-in directives (a.k.a. directives provided directly by the framework) are usually straight-forward : their usage is very simple.

On this one, we can read

> Lets you add a CSS class to an element when the link's route becomes active.

Under the [description](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive#description) fragment, you will see examples of how to use the directive.

Now, for the methods and variables : at the tpo of the page, you will see a link to the source code :

[image]

This will redirect you to the source code of the directive.

In it, you will see what you have asked for : what the variables are, what they represent, all the declared functions, and what they do.

As you may or may not know, `ngOn` functions are lifecycle hooks : they are functions that are called at certain points in a feature's life.

In that case, you have `ngOnChanges`, which is called everytime the change detection is triggered on the `@Inputs`.

Usually, you don't call those hooks : they call functions themselves, but they aren't called.

Now, for the `isActive` flag : you **can** use it.

To use it, you will have to read the decorator of the directive :

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[routerLinkActive]',
  exportAs: 'routerLinkActive',
})
```

What is interesting is the second property, `exportAs`.

This property, as explained in the [explanation of a directive](https://angular.io/api/core/Directive) does the following :

> The name or names that can be used in the template to assign this directive to a variable. For multiple names, use a comma-separated string.

Without going too deep under the hood, (you can find examples of it throughout all the documentation), it allows you to associate a directive instance to a variable, through your template.

The notation for it is

```
<div #myTemplateVariable="exportAsValue"></div>
```

In the case of the `routerLinkActive` directive, it would give

```
<div #RLO="routerLinkActive"></div>
```

**But**, `exportAs` don't create directives. Directives are created through their selector, remember ? And here, our selector is `[routerLinkActive]` : that means

> Every HTML element that has a `routerLinkActive` attribute.

So you will need to add that selector :

```
<div routerLinkActive #RLO="routerLinkActive"></div>
```

From there, you now have an instance of `RouterLinkActive` in your `RLO` variable.

This means you can now do

```
<div *ngIf="RLO.isActive">This is displayed only if the router link of the element is active</div>
```

From now on, your div will only be displayed when the router link from your element is active.

I thinks I have explained the biggest part ...

... I hope this bunch of text helped you, and if you have any question, feel free to ask me and I'll answer you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comprehensive answer! I didn't knew that I can use those properties when I define template variables! But anyway, what is the reason of listing all those callbacks as output properties if their call is useless? I think it would have been a better idea to make them output properties... Btw: I think it's `RouterLinkActive` instead of `RouterLinkActiveDirective`

Comment: I guess they used a library to generate documentation, such as [compodoc](https://compodoc.app) : because the methods must be public (as defined in the interfaces), they appear in the documentation. But again, you know that lifecycle hooks aren't to be called once you read the documentation, so that's an understanding that you leave them unused :) thank you for the typo !